# How to display information in a div outside the map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I tried a bit around and created a simple map with two polygons(most of the code I got from the [Interactive Choropleth Map Tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)).
I added a `"L.control()"` to show information about the polygons in a `div`.
Contrary to the tutorial I would like to have this `div` outside the map.

To get a clue what I mean please look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tbr9p/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/7R5q3/). You just call the update method on the outside div, not the L.control element. I used JQuery for easier selection of the div.

Comment: Second. Nice example.

Comment: Thanks for your help @zimmi. I got it work now [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RHTYF/)

Answer (score 0):

This is also an answer - you can use the appendTo function:

$("#source")
    .appendTo("#destination");

I found the answer [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279957/how-to-move-an-element-into-another-element):